# Handle alerts on Galen framework JS

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, galen

I´ve been developing on Galen for a while now but I´ve encountered a wall when handling alerts on the tests. In this case, after a couple of steps on the test, there´s an alert that pops-up and it requires authentication to proceed with the test.

I´ve already tried using driver.switchTo().alert() but this doesn´t work at all. The only way I´ve been able to go around it in another projects using the Java function `((HasAuthentication) webDriver).register(() -> new UsernameAndPassword("admin", "admin"));`. Now, as far as I know this only works in Java and I haven´t found any alternative for JS on Galen.

This is my Galen test and I´ve commented on the steps where the alert appears.

The alert in question:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iose5.png)

Thanks!

```
// First, the pages document is loaded so the page elements can be used on the test
load("Pages\\ACloginPages.js");

// In this function, which is done before the test, the web page is loaded and the driver is created
beforeTest(function () {
    driver = createDriver("***", "2030x1140");
    session.put("driver", driver);
});

//Here the different viewports are declared and later used on the test
var devices = {
    mobile:{
        deviceName:"mobile",
        tags:["mobile"],    
        size: "500x844"
    },
    desktop:{
        deviceName:"desktop",
        tags:["desktop"],
        size:"1920x1080"
    },
    tablet:{
        deviceName:"tablet",
        tags:["tablet"],
        size:"820x1180"
    }
};

// On the test function, the web driver is executed and it navigates to the beta web page before 
// Executing the UI test, note that the viewports declared above are used here on the test.
forAll(devices, function(){
    test("My trips page on ${deviceName} final", function(device){
    var driver = session.get("driver");

    
    var legacyPage = new LegacyPage(driver);
    legacyPage.waitForIt("200s");
    
    legacyPage.betaButton.click();


    var loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    loginPage.waitForIt("200s");

    ** ALERT APPEARS HERE **
    loginPage.loginUser.typeText("ValdezHarper_IBE@ae-qa1-aircanada.mailinator.com");
    loginPage.loginPassword.typeText("Abc@123456");
    loginPage.loginSubmit.click();
    GalenPages.sleep(15000);


    var flightsTab = new FlightsTab(driver);
    flightsTab.tripType.waitForIt("200s");
 
    ** ALERT APPEARS HERE **
    flightsTab.bookPoints.click();    
    flightsTab.tripType.click();
    GalenPages.sleep(5000);

    flightsTab.multicitySelect.click();
    flightsTab.tripClose.click();
    GalenPages.sleep(5000);

    flightsTab.add1Stopover.click();
    flightsTab.add2Stopover.click();
    GalenPages.sleep(3000);

    resize(driver, device.size);
    checkLayout(driver,"Gspecs\\HP-3444.gspec",device.tags);
    });
});


//After the test is donde the driver closes
afterTest(function() {
    var driver = session.get("driver");
    driver.quit();
});
```

I´ve tried using chromedriver alert blocking capabilities and the switchTo().alert() selenium method but neither of those works.

Comment: That's not an alert, it sounds like basic auth. You can try putting it in the url (https://user:pass@url) and if that doesn't work I think you have to switch to puppeteer / playwright

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I´ve used this approach for the initial authentication when the page is loaded, but this same message pops up different times during the test, more speciffically whenever a new page is loaded

Comment: in playwright you just do page.authenticate({username, password}) - I don't think selenium has anything for it though.